# Determining Big-o While Loop

Tags: algorithm, while-loop, big-o

// n > 0

```
i ← 0 
while (i < n) 
     j ← 0 
     while (j < power(2,i)) 
         j ← j + 1 
     done 
    i ← i + 1 
done
```

Is the overall complexity O(n(log(n)) because the inner while loop has a conditional where 2^i so 2^0  2^1   2^2 ... = 1  2  8 16 32 64 128... etc. So for 2^i < n --> log(n) > i?

And the outer loop looks to be simply O(n).

Multiple both loop complexities for O(n(log(n)), confirm please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. You need to re-examine the inner loop. Remember that log(n) grows more slowly than n. And notice the rate at which 2^n grows. 1,2,4,8... also, why'd you skip 2^2?

Comment: looks like O(n) with the 1 while outside initially, the while with power(2,i), maybe be O(log n) so by my calculations maybe O(n log n)? It's been a while since I've done Big Oh notation.

Comment: @user3818430 you've got it backwards, j increments up to 2^i < 2^n.

Comment: To clarify Ben's comment, something like `while ( power(2,j) < i )` would give an inner `log i`.

Answer (score 5):

It's `O(2^n)`

For the outer loop, the number of iterations is n, so the inner loop executes for every value of i from 0 to n-1.
The number of iterations of the inner loop each time is `2^i`, so the **total** number of iterations for the entire program is:

```
2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 + ... +2^(n-1)
```

This sum is equal to `2^n - 1`. Because 2^n is so large compared to 1, we can drop the 1 in the big-O notation, giving us `O(2^n)`.

Answer (score 3):

Using a formal methodology through Sigma notation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

looks like O(2^n), inner loop is a sum of (2^i) from i=0 to i=n-1, which sums to 2^(i)-1 operations

Comment: You shouldn't be multiplying it by the complexity of the outer loop. It's already accounted for in the sum.

Comment: was your answer before O(n2^n)? I mean, technically, if it is O(2^n), it is O(n2^n)...:p. But that's a good catch by @McLovin

Comment: Actually, `O(n 2^n)` is not equivalent to `O(2^n)`. No matter what the constants are, there is always a value of n above which the first function will be bigger than the second. However, `2^n` and `2^n + n` are equivalent.

Comment: I don't mean that they are equivalent, just that if f(n) is O(2^n), f is also O(n2^n), for the reason you said.

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment. You're right, algorithms bounded by `O(2^n)` are a subset of those bounded by `O(n 2^n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
i ← 0 
while (i < n) 
    j ← 0 
    while (j < power(2,i)) 
         j ← j + 1 
    done 
    i ← i + 1 
done
```

**Time Complexity**

```
Time = 2^0 + (2^0 + 2^1) + .. + (2^0 + .. + 2^(n-1))

Time = n * 2^0 + (n-1) * 2^1 + .. + (n-(n-1)) * 2^(n-1)

Time = SUM { (n-k) * 2^k | k = 0..(n-1) }

Time = 2^(n+1) - n - 2

Time ~ O(2^(n+1))
```